# Move additional attributes below short description

Tags: magento2, layout, attributes

I want to move additional infos **below short description**.
I found this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.attributes" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info" />
        <move element="product.info.overview" destination="page.main.title" />
    </body>
</page>
```

which works fine in "catalog_product-view.xml, but sets additional infos below cart button.
What is the right way, to solve this?

Comment: what kind of additional infos ? can you explain more ?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Create `catalog_product_view.xml` in your theme `Magento_Root/app/design/frontend/Yourtheme/Magento_Catalog/layout`

And paste below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.attributes" destination="product.info.main" after="container_product_primary_1"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Option 2: If you have existing theme then add just below mentioned code inside `<body>` of `Magento_Root/app/design/frontend/Yourtheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<move element="product.attributes" destination="product.info.main" after="container_product_primary_1"/>
```

[image]

Comment: THX for your answer.

Comment: The description of my concern was misunderstanding. Sorry for that! I want to replace short description with long description and add short description below title. And then additional info below the long description. Please see here: [link](https://manurado.de/testring.html)

Answer (score 0):

As per question request **after the overview (short description)** need to load other product attribute data.

in magento **product.info.overview** block is responsible to load **short description (overview)**.

**so for example** *moving sku attribute section after overview*.

create a xml file `catalog_product_view.xml` in your theme at `app/design/frontend/[NAMESPACE]/[THEME]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` **if not exist** (

> if you using luma copy catalog_product_view.xml file in Magento_Catalog  will be exist

else copy the content from **parent theme** or from **Magento_Catalog module**).

add below line (best place is to add move tab before body close tag to avoid any issue)

```
<move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
```

you can change **product.info.stock.sku** to your require **attribute**.

hope it will work for you as it tested.

Comment: THX for your answer.

Comment: @Bingo, if it help and solve your concern then please it as valid answer. so in future others can also use as a reference. :)

Comment: @ Kanhaiya lal How can I tag this as valid answer?

Comment: The description of my concern was misunderstanding. Sorry for that! I want to replace short description with long description and add short description below title. And then additional info below the long description. Please see here: [link](https://manurado.de/testring.html)

Comment: @Bingo as per your asked question, i answered, any way no issue hope you got your output as per your need, but for future if you have any query, please mention everything in question so no one can  misunderstood.